# Эффект нежелательного блюра в выпадающем списке

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Есть такой выпадающий список, в нем небольшой баг, когда появляется сам список во время наведения на него можно заметить на элементах списка легкий блюр. С чем это связано? Предполагаю что это происходит из за трансформации. Кто знает как это можно пофиксить?

```css
.language {
  max-width: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

.language:hover .language_list {
  transform: translate(0, 45px);
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
 }
    
.language__output {
 padding: 5px 20px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #666;
 cursor: pointer;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
.language__output span.out {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.language__output span.out:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.language_list {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 min-width: 117px;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 transform: translate(-50%, 60px);
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
 transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.language_list:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: 11;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.language__item {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 8px;
 display: block;
 font-family: Arial;
 line-height: 1em;
 color: #666;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.language__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none
}
.language__item:hover, .language__item:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}

.language:hover .language_list {
  transform: translate(-50%, 45px);
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="language">
  <div class="language__output">
    <span class="out">En</span>
  </div>
  <div class="language_list">
    <a href="#" class="language__item">English</a>
    <a href="#" class="language__item">Русский</a>
    <a href="#" class="language__item">Español</a>
    <a href="#" class="language__item">German</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Переделайте анимацию

Comment: @Даниил Каким образом? Возможно у вас есть какие то варианты?

Comment: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch